# iTunes Submit/Validate something wrong?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I try to submit or validate a new beta version of my app to test flight but i always get a wired error, i tried it from different computer and as well from different internet connections.

Yesterday i could upload a build with no problems, now i want to bring a fix via itunes connect and test flight

if i use validate:
[image: via Validate]

if i use submit its simply sucked here:
[image: via submit]

Anyone a idea whats wrong here?

Comment: You need to select Export instead of Submit if you want to Submit app to test flight using development of adhoc distribution profile

Comment: Hello @Bhumit not anymore, you can now Submit to testflight (after Apple bought it) directly via iTunes Connect

Answer (score 1):

Faced same problem several days ago. First of all, try to restart xcode, probably you did it. But then try to re-archieve you app, I mean rebuild the package once more. Me helped only rebuilding, lost several hours trying to upload the same archieve.